# Table not created in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I was trying to insert values in a database using SQLite .

Here is my code for Adapter :

```
public class ReminderDatabaseAdapter {
 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "REMINDER_DATABASE";
 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "REMINDER_TABLE";
 public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
 public static final String USERNAME = "USERNAME";
 public static final String REMINDER_TYPE = "REMINDER_TYPE";
 public static final String ASSIGNMENT_STARTTIME = "ASSIGNMENT_STARTTIME";
 public static final String ASSIGNMENT_ENDTIME = "ASSIGNMENT_ENDTIME";
 public static final String REMINDER_DATE = "REMINDER_DATE";
 public static final String REMINDER_TIME = "REMINDER_TIME";
 public static final String DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";
 private ReminderDataBaseHelper sqLiteHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
 private Context context;

 public ReminderDatabaseAdapter(Context c){
      context = c;
     }
 public ReminderDatabaseAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
          sqLiteHelper = new ReminderDataBaseHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
          sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
          return this; 
     }       
    public ReminderDatabaseAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
          sqLiteHelper = new ReminderDataBaseHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
          sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          return this; 
    }    
    public void close(){
         sqLiteHelper.close();
    }

    public int insertEntry(String userName,String reminderType,String assignmentStart,String assignmentEnd,String reminderDate,String reminderTime,String desription){
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        newValues.put("REMINDER_TYPE", reminderType);
        newValues.put("ASSIGNMENT_STARTTIME", assignmentStart);
        newValues.put("ASSIGNMENT_ENDTIME",assignmentEnd);
        newValues.put("REMINDER_DATE",reminderDate);
        newValues.put("REMINDER_TIME",reminderTime );
        newValues.put("DESCRIPTION", desription);

        Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, " USERNAME=? AND REMINDER_DATE=? AND REMINDER_TIME=?", new String[]{userName,reminderDate,reminderTime}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) 
        {
            cursor.close();
            sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, newValues);
            Toast.makeText(context, "REMINDER INSERTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "REMINDER WITH CURRENT DATE AND TIME EXISTS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return 0;
        }   
    }
```

}

Also for Database helper i have following code :

```
public class ReminderDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "REMINDER_DATABASE";
 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "REMINDER_TABLE";
 public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
 public static final String USERNAME = "USERNAME";
 public static final String REMINDER_TYPE = "REMINDER_TYPE";
 public static final String ASSIGNMENT_STARTTIME = "ASSIGNMENT_STARTTIME";
 public static final String ASSIGNMENT_ENDTIME = "ASSIGNMENT_ENDTIME";
 public static final String REMINDER_DATE = "REMINDER_DATE";
 public static final String REMINDER_TIME = "REMINDER_TIME";
 public static final String DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";

 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
          "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
          + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
          + USERNAME + " text not null, "
          + REMINDER_TYPE + " text not null, "
          + ASSIGNMENT_STARTTIME + " text not null, "
          + ASSIGNMENT_ENDTIME + " text not null, "
          + REMINDER_DATE + " text not null, "
          + REMINDER_TIME + " text not null, "
          + DESCRIPTION + " text not null);";
  public ReminderDataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,
    CursorFactory factory, int version) {
      super(context, name, factory, version);
  }
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
  }
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+MYDATABASE_TABLE+";");
    onCreate(db);
  }
 }
```

But I dont know why app is crashing.
Here is logcat :

```
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780): Process: com.example.loginphase, PID: 26780
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: REMINDER_TABLE (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM REMINDER_TABLE WHERE  USERNAME=? AND REMINDER_DATE=? AND REMINDER_TIME=?
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
11-05 13:51:28.463: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
```

And in Fragment am using it like this :

```
private ReminderDatabaseAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
mySQLiteAdapter = new ReminderDatabaseAdapter(rootView.getContext());
mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();        mySQLiteAdapter.insertEntry(name,ReminderType,assignmentBegin,assignmentEnd,reminderdate,remindertime ,descriptionDetails);
```

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the app or change the version number?

Comment: Do what @Nabin says, and also check the log if there is any error creating your table.

Comment: @Nabin yeah , i did try that

Comment: Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, " USERNAME=? AND REMINDER_DATE=? AND REMINDER_TIME", new String[]{userName,reminderDate,reminderTime}, null, null, null); investigate this line only

Comment: @Nabin I updated the post with new logcat details

Comment: Change `DROP TABLE` to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`... or just uninstall the app.

Comment: @laalto Again back to same logcat that i posted at the first

Comment: "no such table" or wrong number of bind args? You're missing `=?` at the end of the query string.

Comment: @laalto I edited that later.But still same error

Comment: Please update the question with the code and stacktrace you're having problems with now.

Answer (score 0):

only thing i see is that you should be already having the database file in your app data folder with version 1 which doesn't contain that REMINDER_TABLE(that was created in first run). This kind of errors normally happens during development time

eighter unistall and istall the app so that onCreate of database helper is called. or increase the db version to 2 and try( MYDATABASE_VERSION = 2;) so that onUpgrade is called.